# Where can I find inclusive $p^+p^+ \to W^+W^-+X^{++}$ cross-section prediction at $14 TeV$ (NNLO)?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, large-hadron-collider, scattering-cross-section

The title self explains.. I desperately need the theoretical NNLO (also NLO can work) prediction for inclusive diboson production (WW), a link to a paper would make my week!

Comment: Please correctly write the process. The charge is _not_ conserved in $pp\to W^+W^-$.

Comment: The term "inclusive" normally refers to every process of the type $pp \to W^+W^-+X$, because I actually don't care to the co-products of the interaction (e.g. b-quarks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual most recent cross-section measurement is in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5243